# Joomla is not showing main content

Tags: php, joomla, joomla2.5

I'm using Joomla! 2.5.19 and I've this code to show content:

```
<div id="avatar-pos-main-body">
    <jdoc:include type="component" />
</div>
```

But it doesn't show anything. I don't have a MultiLanguage website and I've disabled SEF or URL Rewrite (also deleted .htaccess).

This is a screenshot of what I see:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/miNyS.png

Even if you don't know italian Language, you can check that under the top horizontal menu there is just the breadcrumbs section.
The boxes are just a pre-footer content.
That page (I mean article for Joomla) has a lot of text, so I should be able to see it. But nothing is displayed.

Lookind at the source code of the page (with Google Chrome console) I can't see the mainbody class rendered!

Suggestions?

EDIT - Link to my test website: http://test.7it.it:81/integra1/index.php?option=com_content&view=featured&id=143

Comment: can you provide a link to your site? Can't really give a definitive answer with such little information

Comment: Yes, http://test.7it.it:81/integra1/index.php?option=com_content&view=featured&id=143

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me as if your home page **may** be set to show featured articles.

From article manager, try setting an article as featured and check if this makes a difference on the home page.

FYI, I think this is completely unrelated but I'm seeing a 404 for the stylesheet 
http://test.7it.it:81/integra1/templates/st_king/showcases/-1/css/style.css

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks but it seems making no difference. I've set an article as featured but in home page as in another page (new menu item copied from home page) it doesn't show the content.

Comment: @s.milziadi does article content show as you would expect on pages other than the home page? What happens if you change the site template to Ja_purity or Rhuk_milkyway?

Comment: No, the home page is the only page that it's showing correctly. Also with default templates the problem is still here, so, no content (articles) on other single page.